# Safe Water Boiled Lentils

Tags: food-safety, food-science, temperature, vegetables, boiling

**What are the guidelines for safe water boiled lentils?**

Like the [Big Thaw](https://www.fsis.usda.gov/food-safety/safe-food-handling-and-preparation/food-safety-basics/big-thaw-safe-defrosting-methods#:%7E:text=Raw%20or%20cooked%20meat%2C%20poultry,freezing%20can%20begin%20to%20multiply.) from USDA

Comment: Comments removed; see https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3843/did-i-do-what-cascabel-advised-me-to-maybe-i-didnt-understand-correctly-what-d

Answer (score 3):

Such guidelines do not exist.

The FDA (and other agencies with a similar scope of tasks, in the USA and internationally) only create standards and regulations where they see a need for it. Apparently, they have not seen a need to issue a standard for cooking lentils. The most likely reason is that the commonly used ways for cooking lentils (as opposed to the commonly used ways for thawing meat) haven't been sending people to hospitals.

So, it doesn't matter how you cook your lentils. As long as you follow the the other safety guidelines for cooked food (such as refrigerating them afterwards), they are officially considered safe.

Comment: As per discussions on comments and meta: This is the answer to the current formulation of the question. It may not say what you wanted to know, but it is *the answer to this question*, as interpreted by our standards. The question might not cover what you wanted to ask, but I don't see how you can write a different question that is acceptable for our site.

Comment: For what it's worth, it's also possible to infer that they regard boiled lentils as sufficiently safe from the fact that there are recipes on the USDA website that simply boil them: https://wicworks.fns.usda.gov/resources/what-do-i-do-lentils They're basically in the same category as government advice for "how do I safely cook pasta".